# I have 2 tables, same structure but in 2nd table some rows missing. How do you update table 2nd table without using update and joins? using sql

Tags: sql, plsql, ssis, ssrs-2012

I have 2 tables, same structure but in 2nd table some rows missing. How do you update table 2nd table without using update and joins?

Using sql

Comment: `Insert Into` or a CTE... pick one... If you want help show us what you have tried...

Comment: You mean that second table should be an exact copy of the first? Delete from 2nd table, select from first insert into second... But why would anyone need that?

Comment: @Axel he is saying table 1 is good but table 2 is missing records from table 1. He wants to add the missing records to table 2 ... without updates and or joins. First if data isn't there it won't be an update, it would be an insert... I think OP is confused..

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at Merge.

```
MERGE INTO table2 tb2
   USING table1 tb1
   ON tb2.col1 = tb1.col1
   and tb2.col2 = tb1.col2
   .
   . 
   .
   <more columns>

   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE 
    SET tab2.col1 = tab1.col1
        .
        .
        .
        <columns you wand to update>

   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (tab2.col1, tab2.col2 .....<all columns>))
     VALUES (tab1.col1 , tab1.col1 .....<all columns>);
```